# How to create a function to Find books with an author that has < 4 characters in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Please help! How to create a function to Find books with an author that has < 4 characters?

```
const books = [
        {
            "id": "a5b16ad1bb2e96b8c649da7150ad5726",
            "title": "Mon Oct 17 2022 21:32:42 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
            "author": "Ana"
        },
        {
            "id": "221517d1a0948a2faa56a824803aa60e",
            "title": "bjlci",
            "author": "Lea Ann"
        },
        {
            "id": "286332e30d3962f5de20c2cf8b673482",
            "title": "Mon Oct 24 2022 00:38:43 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
            "author": "Ana Lee"
        },
        {
            "id": "bd78bed71d601bdd19c76c8309287894",
            "title": "Mon Oct 17 2022 21:32:42 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
            "author": "Lee"


    }
]
```

This is what I have so far:
it gives me erroe message TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

```
function shortNameAuthors(books){
    for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
        if (books["author"].length <4){
            console.log(books[i]);
        }
    }
  }
  console.log (shortNameAuthors(books))
```

Comment: `books` is an array. Arrays do not have an `author` property. You mean `books[i].author`.

Comment: Thank you! It makes so much sense why it wasn't working before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function shortNameAuthors(books) {
   const filteredBooks = books.filter(
     book => book.author.length < 4
   )

   return filteredBooks
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark my answer as corrent and close this question.